# Problems with git ftp push/clone

Tags: git

I have a server without https and so I'm trying to establish if I can host a
repository there using ftp.  The manuals suggest that I can, but when I try:

```
>git push -v ftp://user:pw@host//u/path/repos/test/.git/ 
Pushing to ftp://user:pw@host//u/path/repos/test/.git/ 
fatal: unable to access 'ftp://host//u/path/repos/test/.git/': RETR response: 550
```

Looking at it with wireshark, I can see the SIZE and the RETR of
.../test/.git/info/refs reports the file does not exist, which is correct and,
as far as I can see, acceptable to git, but that the RETR failure terminates the push:

[image]

I have the same error if I create the repo on the server and they try to CLONE to my PC.

Have I made an error in the setup of my repos, or some other foolish mistake?

Comment: Git does not support FTP out of the box. Have you installed <https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftpi/>?

Comment: Hi @knittl.  Thanks for this, seems I was reading some out of date material.  I can't find the package you're referencing, only https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp and https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp, both of which help with deployment of files to an ftp server, but neither of which seems to help with connecting to a git repo without a secure protocol, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Haven't had a detailed look at the github projects, I have only read their abstract. But again: AFAIK Git does not support pushing/fetching over FTP (only https/ssh for pushing and http/https/ssh for fetching)